# Container not reachable from extern anymore (although localhost works)

Tags: docker, networking

Good morning,

I have a docker setup of 4 docker containers. Two of them contain a wildfly as java application server.

Normally, the wildflys are accessible from extern (direct connection).

Sometimes it happens that it's not accessible from extern (`http://fqdn:8080`) anymore but if I use a `wget http://localhost:8080` I get the index document without problems.

The other wildfly behaves the same - so it seems, something is messing with the network.

A restart of the docker daemon (`systemctl restart docker`) fixes the problem - but that's not a nice solution for a productive running system.

I checked `netstat`, `iptables`, `ifconfig`, `route` in broken and fixed condition and could not find relevant differences.

Has someone an idea what I could do / check / look at the next time it doesn't work anymore? (It happend two times within two weeks but there is no timely correlation between the incidents).

Thank you very much!
Thomas

Comment: See  `iptables -t nat`

Comment: Thank you, I tried. I can trigger the problem by simply restarting the `network.service`. But I didn't see any differences in the `iptables -t nat -L -n` output. `systemctl restart docker` fixes (again) the problem. But I still have no clue what docker is doing by starting because I couldn't find any relevant differences.

Comment: It adds a `Chain DOCKER`

Comment: Thank you, but after restarting the network, nothing changed there :shrug: